# How to refine Dijkstra's Algorithm, Not Finding Optimal Path

Tags: c++, debugging, dijkstra, path-finding

Here is my implementation of the well known Dijkstra algorithm:

```
std::vector<unsigned> RouteFinder::findPathBetweenIntersections(unsigned intersect_id_start, unsigned intersect_id_end) {

    //Get number of intersections and reference graph from streetGraph class
    StreetGraph* streetGraph = StreetGraph::getGraphPointer();
    unsigned intersectionCount = streetGraph->getIntersectioncount();
    std::vector<attachedSegments> referenceGraph = streetGraph->getStreetGraph();

    /*Initialize:
     * min_distance: Min Distance to get to index node
     * active_vertices: The nodes to check next
     * cameAlong: Street Segments used to get to the node
     * cameFrom: Intersections taken to get to a node
     */
    vector<double> min_distance( intersectionCount, DBL_MAX );
    min_distance[ intersect_id_start ] = 0.0;

    set< pair<double,unsigned> > active_vertices;
    active_vertices.insert( {0.0,intersect_id_start} );

    vector<unsigned> cameAlong(intersectionCount,UINT_MAX);

    vector<unsigned> cameFrom(intersectionCount,0);

    //For each node in active_vertices
    while (!active_vertices.empty()) {
        unsigned currentNode = active_vertices.begin()->second;
        if (currentNode == intersect_id_end) return buildPath(cameFrom, cameAlong, currentNode, intersect_id_start);
        active_vertices.erase( active_vertices.begin() );
        for (auto edge : referenceGraph[currentNode].streetSegments) 
            if (min_distance[get<2>(edge)] > min_distance[currentNode] + get<0>(edge)) {

                //If the new distance is better than the one that is there
                //Remove the previous data
                active_vertices.erase( { min_distance[get<2>(edge)], get<2>(edge) } );
                //Calculate the better distance and replace it
                min_distance[get<2>(edge)] = min_distance[currentNode] + get<0>(edge);

                //Add 15 seconds if the street has changed
                if ((cameAlong[currentNode] != UINT_MAX
                        && getStreetSegmentInfo(cameAlong[currentNode]).streetID != getStreetSegmentInfo(get<1>(edge)).streetID)
                        ) {
                    min_distance[get<2>(edge)] = min_distance[get<2>(edge)] + .25;
                }

                active_vertices.insert( { min_distance[get<2>(edge)], get<2>(edge) } );

                //Record where you came from
                cameAlong[get<2>(edge)] = get<1>(edge);
                cameFrom[get<2>(edge)] = currentNode;
            }
    }

    //Return nothing if nothing found
    vector<unsigned> nothing;
    return nothing;
}
```

My graph is a vector of structures called "intersectionNode". Each "intersectionNode" has a vector (among other useful info) of `tuple<double weight,int streetSegment,int nextIntersection>`.

I adapted my implementation from examples I found online and from friends, it is pretty fast. But it does not seem to return the fastest path. Does anything jump out to you as wrong, any hints for debugging?

Also, I have incorporated a run penalty of .25 minutes (15 seconds).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! When comparing new paths against old paths. I did not take into account the turning costs. Thanks guys...